# WIFI is so slow with Kubuntu 20.04 in notebook HP

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, hp, realtek

I tried all from all forums and I can't fix this problem. I receive 40 mbps from 100 mbps.

This is my wireless controller:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]

My kernel is 5.11.0.31-generic

`ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:ce:62:1a:0c:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0

3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:c5:f2:26:fa:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp2s0
```

After running the commands to set MTU, all is the same:

[image: speed test]

Comment: Without knowing in detail what you tried, how can anyone here make a suggestion? I would hate to invest 20+ minutes of my free time writing up an answer with details and examples only to waste your time by suggesting something you've already done ...

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices, but you've provided no details as to which you're using, or if you've tried both. Details are helpful in letting know what you've done so we can what to suggest, and what not to suggest.   (FYI: *you may already know this, but drivers are technically kernel modules; so the stack choice chosen can make a significant difference*)

Comment: @guiverc info updated